# SSLContext that does no encryption

Tags: python-3.x, ssl

Is it possible is construct an [SSLContext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext) that does *no* encryption over the underlying socket, and just passes data straight through, so the remote server does not need to be SSL/TLS aware in any way?

This might seem slightly pointless, but am investigating how code paths can be kept as similar as possible between encrypted and non-encrypted connections, e.g. if can have something like

```
encrypted_opts = ...
non_encrypted_opts = ...
context = SSLContext(**(encrypted_opts if encrypt else non_encrypted_opts))
ssl_socket = context.wrap_socket(socket, ...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dummy SSLContext that returns a socket that appears to behave like an SSLSocket

```
from socket import socket

class NonSSLContext():
    def wrap_socket(self, sock, *_, **__):
        sock.__class__ = NonSSLSocket
        return sock

class NonSSLSocket(socket):
    __slots__ = ()

    def do_handshake(self):
        pass

    def unwrap(self):
        self.__class__ = socket
        return self
```

which you can use as (for example)

```
from ssl import SSLContext

encrypted_context = SSLContext(...
non_encrypted_context = NonSSLContext(...
context = encrypted_context if encrypt else non_encrypted_context
socket = ...
ssl_socket = context.wrap_socket(sock, ...
...
ssl_sock.do_handshake()
...
```